# How can I get Breeze.js to save my timezone in my SQL DB

Tags: date, angularjs, breeze

We are trying to sort out how to have a user input a date-time with a timezone and save that in my SQL database.  I have a column of type datetimeoffset in my SQL server.

```
   $scope.saveItemChanges = function ()
{
    var td = new Date();

    $scope.chosenEditItem.ServiceStatusUpdateDateTimeOffset = td;

    $log.info( td.toString() + "ISO " + td.toISOString()  + "UTC " + td.toUTCString() + "JSON " + td.toJSON());
    mainDataService.saveChanges()
        .then (saveSucceededCloseEdit)
        .fail (displayErrors)
}
```

In my database I'm not seeing the timezone.  Only rows 1007-1009 got inserted via breeze the other rows are testing.
[image]

Basically I want to be able to capture the date-time and timezone on the client and store it in my DB.  When someones goes back to view the record I need to be able to determine what timezone the date-time is for.  I'm not sure what I'm missing in the path from Client -> Server that is stopping the timezone from being saved in the DB.

[Breeze Date Info](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/date-time)  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/date-time

Console logging:
[image]
[image]

Database record:
[image]

Comment: that `-06:00` is the time zone.

Comment: The problem is rows 1007-1009 got inserted via Breeze.  They should have all been Central Time zone.

Comment: Ok, can you compare the data logged by $log.info and stored in the db? can you post some of the data?

Comment: Yes, when we log it to the console we see the timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript treats all dates as UTC, but you can still change it on the server.

First, you will need to know what the timezone on the client is and send it to the server. You can do this by having an unmapped property (i.e. won't be saved to the DB):

```
var UnusualDate = function () {
   this.timezoneOffset = 0;
};
em.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("UnusualDate", UnusualDate);

var td = new Date();
var uD = em.createEntity("UnusualDate", { creationDate: td });       
uD.setProperty("timezoneOffset", td.getTimezoneOffset()/-60);
```

Then, on the server BeforeSaveEntity or BeforeSaveEntities, you retrieve the timezone offset and reset the date accordingly:

```
var timezoneOffset = Convert.ToInt32(entityInfo.UnmappedValuesMap["timezoneOffset"]);
UnusualDate uDate = entityInfo.Entity as UnusualDate;
uDate.CreationDate = uDate.CreationDate.ToOffset(new TimeSpan(timezoneOffset, 0, 0));
```

If you are not familiar with BeforeSaveEntity and BeforeSaveEntities, you can take a look at the documentation at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider-methods.